# How to boxplot an external file (.dat)?

Tags: octave, boxplot

I made an octave file that saves a 8*10 matrix in file.dat,now I want to make a boxplot of this data,what command to use in cygwin/terminal to boxplot this file.dat, someone told me ,its like $boxplot load("file.dat") but its not working ,please help.

PS:I have already downloaded statistics package.

Comment: Your question does not make a lot of sense. What's your problem exactly? It's in the reading of the file with Octave or in actually making the boxplot? If you want to make a boxplot with Octave why are you saving the data in a file? Just use the [boxplot](http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/boxplot.html) function.